# Knapsack but can choose an item more than one time?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

KNAPSACK problem is old, but this has some differences:

At a store that has n items, each item has weight W[i] and value V[i]. A bag can include maximum weight W. Choose some items, which total have max values. And an item can be chosen more than one time.

I only can finish if an item can be chosen one time but more than one time is hard for me. So can you help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called Unbounded Knapsack. You can read about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unbounded-knapsack-repetition-items-allowed/)